# difference between installing jre using msi and by using jreXXX.exe installer

Tags: windows-installer, java

We have a requirement where jre needed to be installed on machines silently i.e by using /s switch on the command line. Now we see on some cases the installation of jre is over by seeing the msi logs. The windows installer exits with return code o, but the jre installer hangs for over half an hour. Ultimately it had to be killed. This behaviour has been seen many times. To avoid this issue we are extracting the msi and cab files from the jre.exe wrapper and using them directly for installation. 
Now my question is there any difference in these two kinds of installation? Does the installation using msi skips some configuration steps? Will this jre environment is sufficient to run all kind of programs requiring jre?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry, you will have the same if install via bootstrapped exe or via msi. Actually the MSI contains own archive with source files which installs with help of Custom Actions, and bootstrapped Exe needed only for nice User Interface. 
For distribution in SCCM we use extracted MSI for years.

Also useful link on IT-Ninja [How to package JRE](http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-package-java-runtime-environment-jre)